# How to display Bootstrap Submenu on Click?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, submenu

Basically, I want to display a "submenu" on click, when user click on a menu the corresponding submenu will display, not by "hover" which is set as defalut by bootstrap.

bootstrap demo http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#dropdowns (scroll to Sub menus on dropdowns)

Any ideas?

Comment: This question was answered in another post:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386993/twitters-bootstrap-dropdowns-with-click-event

example: http://bootply.com/79868

Answer (score -3):

I was looking at exactly the same thing and it seems that this is not possible at the moment. We should keep an eye out for possible future corrections.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17386993/twitters-bootstrap-dropdowns-with-click-event It looks like there actually is a way.