# Twitter's Bootstrap dropdowns with click event

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm using twitter bootstrap "dropdowns" not a "dropdown" multilevel menu with html markup.

```html
   <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>
                  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
                     <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
                     <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>

                 </ul>
              </li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
              <li class="divider"></li>
              <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
      </li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I have a question. Can I add click event to show submenu?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allow click on twitter bootstrap dropdown toggle link?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12630188/allow-click-on-twitter-bootstrap-dropdown-toggle-link)

Answer (score 5):

The submenus are showed by css. So first disable the css (hover) and add a click event to your menu item.

**html example**:

```html
<div class="dropdown">
<a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Show menu</a>
<ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
   <li class="dropdown-submenu">
    <a tabindex="-1" href="#">More options</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
        <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="divider"></li>
  <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**disable css**:

```css
.dropdown-submenu:hover > .dropdown-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

**trigger the click by javascript**:

```javascript
$('.dropdown-submenu').click(function(){
  $('.dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu').css('display','block');
  return false;
});
```

Example: http://bootply.com/66088

NOTE when you have more as one submenu give each its own class

Comment: With the following modification to the JS, you can have multiple sub-menu's without giving each it's own class:
`$('.dropdown-submenu').click(function(){$(this).children('.dropdown-menu').css('display','block'); return false;});`
Example: http://bootply.com/79868

Comment: If you add this line to JS all the sub-submenus will close when you open sub-menu: $('.dropdown-toggle').click(function () {$(this).parent().children('.dropdown-menu').find('.dropdown-menu').css('display', 'none');});

Comment: I know this is an older question, but I also had a similar problem and I tried this solution. With slight tweaks everything worked except for if I looked at one menu, then went to another none of the links would work. I'll post a solution when I find one

Comment: for hiding  the opened sub-menu when clicking other sub-menu **check other solution** [here](http://www.bootply.com/97919), hope helps someone.